# PCI Serial Bus - Need

Tags: drivers, pci, windows-8-upgrade

I have two entries in device manager after upgrading to windows 8. I followed the directions in a post on this site and it helped to some degree. but I still have two PCI Serial Bus that have no drivers. I am so tired of this. I have an older inspiron that had no trouble with windows 8. It is less of a machine too. Help???

Answer (score 1):

The post at [this forum](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/p/19057729/19180715.aspx#19180715) suggests the following:

> Install chipset, HECI, and ME/SOL drivers (part of intel amt/vpro)

Look on the Dell or computer manufacturer website and see if you can acquire the chipset drivers for your model (Try not to use dodgy "driver helper" sites).  If you cannot find Windows 8 drivers, try the Windows 7 drivers.  Make sure to match the "bitness" of your CPU, which is quite likely 64-bit these days.

I would also upgrade your system to the latest BIOS or UEFI version as that can affect visibility of devices.

Worse comes to worst, you may need to do further searching after finding out the PCI device and vendor ID.  [This site](http://www.ccboot.com/find-ven-dev-id.htm) explains how to do it for a NIC, and while the instructions are for Windows XP the procedure is the same for Windows 7 or 8.

If no hardware you are actually using is working improperly, it really shouldn't be anything you need to worry about.